# Simple Rule Generates this Sequence from Well Known Number Series

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, number-sequence, no-computers

First 6 terms generated on applying the simple rule are displayed here.

5,  8,  18,  102,  322,  1830,  ?,  ?,  ?

Hint 1:

> The number series used to generate the sequence is itself a subset of more well known series.

Hint 2:

> More well known series is the sequence of Prime Numbers.

Hint 3:

> Subset of Primes is Fibonacci Primes.

Comment: Is this the sum/product/difference of **two** well known number series?

Comment: I did not mention 2.....not to be found in oeis....numbers are derived from this series...this concept hasn’t been introduced in none of my puzzles so far..series will become fairly big after ten more terms

Comment: Sorry: "Well Known Number Series" does not contain any article so I can't tell whether "series" is singular or plural.

Comment: It is a singular series.

Comment: I will drop some hints to help. Today I am posting Hint 1.

Comment: I would like this to be closed as there is no interest. I am unable to close it myself.

Comment: Hint 2 is Given today for those interested.

Comment: Hint 3 is Given today for those interested.

Comment: @rubio..I would like to cleanup the puzzles that have no answers and not of much interest..I am unable to delete them like this one.

Comment: What would I flag it as?

Comment: I don’t know..hopefully Rubio will be able to take action

Comment: Answer posted..for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no answer was posted so far, in spite of hints, I am posting an answer. In general, most of my sequences won’t be found in OEIS. They are generated using simple rules based on widely known sequences and they can be regenerated without calculators and computers. They have several practical applications in security and cryptography.

Series:

> Well known Fibonacci Prime Series 
> $2, 3, 5, 13, 89, 233, 1597, 28657, 514229.......$

Rule:

> Sum each Successive Pair

Final Series:

> $5, 8, 18, 102, 322, 1830, 30254, 542886....$